# how to delete $rootScope variable in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

In a controller, I had defined `$rootScope.tableformate` variable to fill data in a popup.

After filling popup data `$rootScope.tableformate` is not used. How to delete this variable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
delete $rootScope.tableformate
```